# Opening another .java file within a GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

**Short and sweet**: I'd like to be able to run another .java file, from the click of a button in a GUI in Netbeans for Mac.

**A little more explanation**:
I am recreating a project I created when I started with java, to make it cleaner. I have done a lot of improvement, though one problem I had with it is that I had too many panels in one JFrame, and I ended up having large amounts of code setting visibilities whenever I change panel.

Eg:

```
jPanel1.setVisible(false);
jPanel2.setVisible(false);
jPanel3.setVisible(true);
```

I know I could just live with it, but I'd like to see if there is a way to separate the code/panels a bit more, as described in the following.
My first thought was to have multiple files; one for each page. Similar to how you would in html.

Therefore, I have LoginPage.java, and GuestMainPage.java.
If it is possible, I'd like to be able to link them, like: ***close LoginPage.java*** and ***open GuestMainPage.java***, on the click of a button.

Basically, I want to be able to make it *compile* or *open* another .java file, when I click a button on my GUI.
(In case it helps, the file would be in the same project.)

**Example** *If there is a way to open another file. Possibly by accessing terminal commands?*

```
public class LoginPage extends javax.swing.JFrame {

//Excluded a bunch of generated code from Netbeans

private void Login(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
//Code executed on Mouse Click of a Button labeled Login.

            if(username.equalsIgnoreCase("guest")){

                  //A bit of pseudocode
                  open(GuestMainPage.java);
                  close(LoginPage.java);

            }
            if(username.equalsIgnoreCase("admin")){

                  open(AdminMainPage.java);
                  close(LoginPage.java);

            }
}
}
```

From research and experience, I know you can access other files, or other classes within the same project - thus the use of objects and such - but I don't know if you can physically run the other file. I'd be able to live with the possibility of being able to access terminal through java. (And then have the power to do basically anything, I just cannot find how to do that either.)

I have looked through a lot of stackoverflow topics to try and find an answer, as well as a lot of googling, but I cannot find one that really answers my question. However, if there really is no way to do this, then I am perfectly happy with an answer confirming that, and if that is the case, I will just have to cope with multiple panels.

Thank you

-Ewan

Comment: You don't "run" .java files. They are source code.

Comment: I just used the term "run", as it is the term Netbeans uses when it compiles the code in order to test it. I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: You ... really seem rather confused as to what source code is vs. compiled classes, and how you instantiate and use them. I really, really suggest a good Beginner's book for Java.

Comment: But I thought Netbeans compiles the code every time you save, and then you literally click the run button, and it executes the compiled code.
Is that not the case? If not, then I think I'm in trouble come exam time.

Oh, and sorry for nagging you with comments! I don't mean to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try implementing an MVC pattern. Take a look at spring: http://www.springsource.org/

Comment: That springsource environment is so liberating compared to netbeans. Makes it much easier to grasp the concept of the MVC.

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't "open" other files like that, nor do you want to. Instead you compile all Java files to class files and use other classes. You can load classes on command using a custom class-loader, but I sincerely doubt that your application really needs that. Instead it just needs some MVC (model-view-controller) structuring (as noted by ilea -- 1+ to them) and forethought.

One decent solution to consider is to use a CardLayout, since this can greatly simplify changing GUI "views" or components shown in a top-level container such as an applet or a JFrame. You can read up on how to use these guys here: [How to use CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 0):

As I see that you are going to do as same as me. Please start this from the little. Let's suppose that I have a ".java" file and I want to run it with the JFRAME button, so can I create this ".java" file into a JAR file and then with the JBUTTON I can run that JAR file with this code.

```
try { 
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("Path of the *.jar File"));     
} catch(IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Try this.

Comment: It is as not as you want but it will help you to get what you want.